# Origin Extract here contract

Tags: pantheon-files, contract

When extracting files in a folder with lots of files, using right click menu > Extract here, it's quite a hassle to locate the extracted files. I usually start a search on the file name. There is also no feedback whether the extraction worked, as the compressed file stays selected, even when a file / folder is added the scroll position is unchanged (Except for in the Grid view).

I would like to get the files that are extracted selected in some way.

This would probably requires adapting the "Extract here" contract file (`/usr/share/contractor/file-roller-extract-here.contract`). I however haven't been able to find the origin of this contract, which package adds it. It doesn't seem to be a part of the [github.com/elementary](https://github.com/elementary) source code, it's also not included in the [file-roller](https://github.com/GNOME/file-roller) code. Does anyone know?

Also see the issue I opened on this, in the not so appropriate place, the elementary Files issue queue: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file-roller contract is part of the patched file-roller package that elementary uses. Currently 3.16.5-0ubuntu1.2+elementary4~ubuntu0.4.1.  You can report issues here: https://github.com/elementary/ubuntu-package-imports/issues

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll do that. It's quite unintuitive, because there is no mention of file-roller or contracts, but therefore I've been so bold to request a readme: https://github.com/elementary/ubuntu-package-imports/issues/2

Comment: The actual .contract file: https://github.com/codygarver/os-patch-file-roller-xenial/blob/master/data/file-roller-extract-here.contract

Comment: This was something that was between migration from Launchpad and GitHub.

Comment: Please clarify, I know that elementary migrated from Launchpad to github, but what does that mean for this repo? It's only just migrated? Or not yet?